# Pass URL of link to callback function with Chrome Extension Context Menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that uses a context menu item to trigger a function. This menu only shows when the user right-clicks a link to certain file type. Now my problem is I need to pass the URL of the link to a function. In the `"onclick"` parameter in `chrome.contextMenus.create()`, I've tried adding various parameters to my callback function. I've tried using the following in my callback:

```
function(linkUrl) { onClickHandler(linkUrl); }
function({"info":["linkUrl"]}) { onClickHandler(linkUrl); }
function("info":["linkUrl"]) { onClickHandler(linkUrl); }
function() { onClicHandler(linkUrl); }
function({"info":["linkUrl"]}) { onClickHandler({"info":["linkUrl"]}); }
function() { onClickHandler({"info":["linkUrl"]}); }
```

I've also tried using `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler(linkUrl));` and `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler({"info":["linkUrl"]});` to no success. It always returns `null`, `undefined`, and `[object Object]`. How do I pass the URL of the link? The API doc doesn't really go into detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wow, that's a mess.*

You need to pass a reference to the function to use it as a callback. Instead..

```
// defines a function that takes 1 parameter and passes it to the handler
function(linkUrl) { onClickHandler(linkUrl); }
// syntax error - you  can only specify a parameter name
function({"info":["linkUrl"]}) { onClickHandler(linkUrl); }
// syntax error
function("info":["linkUrl"]) { onClickHandler(linkUrl); }
// linkUrl does not come from anywhere
function() { onClicHandler(linkUrl); }
// syntax error
function({"info":["linkUrl"]}) { onClickHandler({"info":["linkUrl"]}); }
// Passes a constant object {"info": ["linkUrl"]} to the handler
function() { onClickHandler({"info":["linkUrl"]}); }

// Passes the result of executing onClickHandler(linkUrl) as a function
//  (Which probably does not return a function, and linkUrl is undefined)
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler(linkUrl));

// Passes the result of executing onClickHandler(obj) as a function
//  where obj is that constant object {"info": ["linkUrl"]}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler({"info":["linkUrl"]});
```

[Shotgun debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) much?

---

Your first attempt is closest at working. But you must understand what happens. Let's give an example. Suppose you have an API that returns an object of a very specific form asynchronously:

```
function myAwesomeAPICall(callback) {
  /* ... */
  callback({apples: n, oranges: m});
}
```

It expects a function that will receive that very specific type of object and does something with it. Say, you have a handler of the form

```
function applesAndOranges(numApples, numOranges) {
  /* ... */
}
```

It expects 2 numbers. So you can't just do that:

```
myAwesomeAPICall(applesAndOranges);
```

Since then `numApples` will be an object, and `numOranges` would be undefined. You can name your arguments as you wish, but the structure of `myAwesomeAPICall` does not know your definition: it will just put what it wants to the first argument.

So you need a function that takes an object, and feeds the numbers to your handler.

```
function callbackForAPI(obj) { // obj will have the required format
  applesAndOranges(obj.apples, obj.oranges);
}

myAwesomeAPICall(callbackForAPI);
// Note, it's not callbackForAPI() - that would be passing the result,
//  not the function itself
```

In fact, it does not have to be a named function at all. An anonymous function will do just fine:

```
myAwesomeAPICall(function(obj) {
  applesAndOranges(obj.apples, obj.oranges);
});
```

---

Lesson learned: APIs expect callbacks with a particular format for input.

In fact, [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) say this:

> ```
> chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function callback)
> ```
>
> The *callback* parameter should be a function that looks like this:
>       function(object info, tabs.Tab tab) {...};
>   (description of object `info` follows)

Note the words "should be". Though you're not required to use the parameters passed, you could use just `info`, or nothing, but the expected format for data is as described.

So, finally:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(obj, tab) {
  onClickHandler(obj.linkUrl);
});
```